# Make a new matrix in R considering as reference diagonal of original matrix

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem in R creating a new matrix using as reference the diagonal of original matrix. My matrix is `alfet`, and it has the next form (I add `dput()` version of `alfet` in the final part):

```
         A          B           C            D            E           F
  A 0.79237537 0.01876833 0.005571848 0.0005865103 0.0002932551 0.000000000
  B 0.39622642 0.15723270 0.119496855 0.0503144654 0.0314465409 0.006289308
  C 0.20408163 0.26530612 0.163265306 0.1020408163 0.0204081633 0.081632653
  D 0.03571429 0.00000000 0.035714286 0.3928571429 0.0714285714 0.214285714
  E 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.1111111111 0.3333333333 0.333333333
  F 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.901960784
```

It has six rows and six columns. I want to create a new matrix where considering the elements of diagonal of `alfet`, each column is set in the first row. For example for second column the value of diagonal is `0.15723270` then this value goes to the first row in the same column and the same thing happens for the next elements that are located after `0.15723270` in the same column. I want to get something like this:

```
       A          B           C            D            E              F
A  0.79237537  0.1572327  0.163265306  0.3928571429  0.3333333333  0.901960784
B  0.39622642  0.2653061  0.035714286  0.1111111111  0
C  0.20408163  0          0            0
D  0.03571429  0          0
E  0           0            
F  0
```

I don't know if in R there is any function to make this or some advice to build this new matrix. The `dput()` version of `alfet` is the next:

```
structure(c(0.792375366568915, 0.39622641509434, 0.204081632653061, 
0.0357142857142857, 0, 0, 0.0187683284457478, 0.157232704402516, 
0.26530612244898, 0, 0, 0, 0.00557184750733138, 0.119496855345912, 
0.163265306122449, 0.0357142857142857, 0, 0, 0.000586510263929619, 
0.050314465408805, 0.102040816326531, 0.392857142857143, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.000293255131964809, 0.0314465408805031, 0.0204081632653061, 
0.0714285714285714, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0.00628930817610063, 
0.0816326530612245, 0.214285714285714, 0.333333333333333, 0.901960784313726
), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")), .Names = c("", 
"")))
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What should the empty elements of the matrix be? `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `diag` on a vector of elements to create an empty matrix with that diagonal. So if you pass the diagonal of `alfet` to `diag` you can create a new matrix like so:

```
> new <- diag(diag(alfet))
> new
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.7923754 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000 0.1572327 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1632653 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3928571 0.0000000 0.0000000
[5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000
[6,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.9019608
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
# create an index for lower triangular (including diagonal)
idx <- lower.tri(alfet, diag = TRUE)
# create an index for replacement
idx2 <- apply(idx, 2, rev)

# create a matrix with zeroes
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(alfet), ncol = ncol(alfet))

# replace values 
mat[idx2] <- alfet[idx]
```

The result (`mat`):

```
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.79237537 0.1572327 0.16326531 0.3928571 0.3333333 0.9019608
[2,] 0.39622642 0.2653061 0.03571429 0.1111111 0.0000000 0.0000000
[3,] 0.20408163 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[4,] 0.03571429 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[5,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[6,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

---

If you want `NA`s instead of `0`s, you can create a matrix with `NA`s.

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(alfet), ncol = ncol(alfet))
mat[idx2] <- alfet[idx]
```